# Is there a limit on the number of search service application which can be configured and number of queries

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, enterprise-search, limitations

I'm new to sharepoint and I'm aiming to create an enterprise search application using sharepoint. I have 2 quick questions

1. Is there a limit to the number of search service applications which can be created
2. Is there any limit to the number of queries which can be issued (per month) to a search service application?

I'm interested in both sharepoint online and on-prem (2016)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create more than what you get in SPO, but there is no limit on number of queries in either platform. The question for on-prem would be why do you need to create more than one? You would only do so in response to exceeding a particular limit.

You can find all of the 2016 Search related limits at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/software-boundaries-and-limits-0#limits-and-boundaries.